# iCalendar RRULE/RECUR for Thanksgiving weekend?

Tags: icalendar, vcalendar

Is there an "easy" way to create yearly events for "Thanksgiving weekend", meaning an event starting on the 4th Thursday of November (with Sunday as the first weekday), and ending on the following Sunday?

As nearly as I can tell, things like RRULE and RECUR let you create recurring events with zero duration (ie, points in time), but not recurring events that last over a period of time.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY:4TH;WKST=SU
```

You're definitely not restricted to 0 duration events. You can simply specify a DTSTART and DTEND (or DURATION) to get the full weekend.

Comment: Can DTSTART and DTEND be defined as RRULE's themselves? If not, how do I specify a month long event? The length of a month is not fixed. I should've mentioned that getting the date of Thanksgiving was easy enough, it was the duration part that had me stumped.

Comment: Specifying a month-long event is not part of your original question, but yes it is possible. RRULE applies to both `DTSTART` and `DTEND`, you can't specify it for each separately, but that would also not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Evert's answer, to specify a 4 day long event, you just need to specify the DTSTART and DTEND such as below:

`DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20151126 DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20151130 RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=4TH;WKST=SU`

the justification comes from below section of RFC5545:

> [RFC5545 3.6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1)The "DTSTART" property for a "VEVENT" specifies the inclusive
> start of the event.  For recurring events, it also specifies the
> very first instance in the recurrence set.  The "DTEND" property
> for a "VEVENT" calendar component specifies the non-inclusive end
> of the event.